# switchin back another viewport from the terminal buffer

Tags: terminal-buffer

I created :term, then I switch to another viewport, but latter when I switch back to the term buffer "!/bin/bash" it is full screen and I don't understand how can I access the vim command line again since everything I type is handled by the terminal itself but not by vim.

The only thing I can do is to exit term, but I would like just to switch to another buffer.

Ctrl-W does not work here since the terminal not in a split window anymore if you use ":b N". Thanks

Comment: Is this Vim or Neovim?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I find your question rather unclear—normally, you would do Ctrl-w :, but I’m not sure why your terminal buffer is “full screen” unless you gave some other config. You may want to read https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The OP mentions going back to the buffer 'later', which I think means he hides it then switches back to it in a scenario where there's only one window left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enter vim command-mode from a terminal buffer, you can use: `<c-\>n`.

Then, you will be able to use regular vim commands as in any buffer.

Thus, `:` lets you enter vim command-line and `i` switches back to terminal input as you'd expect.

Comment: great! it works. thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Please consider 'accepting' the answer if this answers your question.